# Vanishing Jacobian determinant

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^n \to \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$ be a dominant morphism. Is it true that there is always a point where the determinant of the Jacobian matrix is not zero? My intuition says that this should be correct, but I can't find a way to proof it at the moment. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be done with less heavy machinery, but it seems that some propositions in Hartshorne solves the problem:

First note that the locus of points where the determinant of the Jacobian matrix is non-zero, is the same as the smooth locus of $f$. This follows for example by Proposition 10.4 in Hartshorne (page 270).

Then use Lemma 10.5, which says that there is an open subset $U \subset \mathbb A^n$ such that $f|U$ is smooth, and on smooth points, the Jacobian is nonzero.

Comment: this should be a typo. I guess you simply have to replace $X$ by $f$

Comment: @Hans Thank you, that was indeed a typo.